# Derive the Legendre differential equation given the recurrence relation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, numerical-calculus

Given the 3-term recurrence relation $$(n+1)P_{n+1}=(2n+1)xP_n-nP_{n-1},$$ prove that $$(1-x^2)P''_n-2xP'_n+n(n+1)P_n=0.$$
I tried differentiate from both sides, but how can I get rid of the different indices?

Comment: See the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials

Comment: Have you tried proving it by recursion?

Comment: What are $P_0,P_1$?